# mkdir -p vs if [[ ! -d dirname ]]

Tags: ksh

Is there any reason to use

```
if [[ ! -d dirname ]]; then mkdir dirname; fi
```

instead of just

```
mkdir -p dirname
```

Answer (score 2):

The first syntax depends on the shell you are using, not the second.

Since both fail if `dirname` exists not as a directory, no, there's no difference.

Comment: I think one should use the `mkdir -p` option, since it is shorter, and allows the recursive creation of directory. But really, it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
-d FILE        True if file is a directory.

-p             no error if existing, make parent directories as needed.
```

If `dirname` does not contain any parents then the two commands behave the same. However if `dirname` contains parents the `-d` will not create those. And `[[` is shell-dependent.

Comment: >>And [[ is shell-dependent.
I know. I am writing scripts for ksh on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

These two ksh commands are functionally the same since both will create a directory called `dirname`.

`mkdir -p dirname` is more elegant.